# How to query list of unique records from many to one relationship data structure?

Tags: sql

I am having trouble finding a suitable query in SQL server. I have department(Table A) having many clients(Table B) data structure. I am looking for a query to retrieve only one client(first occurrence) of each department that the client status is active. any help?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS T1 
WHERE 
    EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * FROM Table2 as T2 
        WHERE T1.Column1 = T2.Column1 AND Column2 = 1
    )
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM Table2 as T2 
        WHERE T1.Column1 = T2.Column1 AND Column2 = 2
    );
```

Comment: What does the Column2 refer to? thanks for the reply

Comment: its based on your where condition. I'm just put it as sample

Answer (score 0):

You could then try using [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

> Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result
>   set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

Something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  d.*,
                c.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.departmentid ORDER BY <SOME ORDER FIELDS>) RowID
        FROm    department d LEFT JOIN
                clients c   ON  <SOME JOIN CONDITION>
                            AND c.[Status] = 'Active'
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Vals
WHERE   RowID = 1
```